# Create a stacked predictive model in R

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I am trying to learn how to create a blended model that trains exclusively off the output of base models. Following suggestions found online (from Johns Hopkins DataScience course), I can do this successfully in the trivial case of being able to train my model on the same labeled test Data that I then predict on.

The process is relatively simple, in theory.

1. Build base models
2. for each model, predict on testing Data
3. combine predictions in newDF, include the labeled outcome from testingData as an additional column.
4. train a combined, or 'meta', model on the newDF. This model should learn to "say" something like: "when mod1 predicts 0, and mod2 predicts 1, etc,etc the most probable true outcome is 0"
5. Repeat steps 2 & 3 on your validation data
6. Use the combined model to make your final predictions on the validation data.

Below, shows a process that works:

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)
set.seed(3433)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(AlzheimerDisease)
adData = data.frame(diagnosis,predictors)
inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3/4)[[1]]
training = adData[ inTrain,]
testing = adData[-inTrain,]


set.seed(62433)
modRF <- train(diagnosis ~., method = "rf", data = training)
modGBM <- train(diagnosis ~., method = "gbm", data = training) 
modLDA <- train(diagnosis ~., method = "lda", data = training, preProcess=c("center","scale")) 

# STACK THE PREDICTIONS
# make predictions
predRF <- predict(modRF,testing)
predGBM <- predict(modGBM, testing)
predLDA <- predict(modLDA, testing)

# Fit a model that combines all (both of the predictors)
predDF <- data.frame(predRF,predGBM,predLDA,diagnosis=testing$diagnosis)
#train a new model on the predictions
combModFit <- train(diagnosis ~.,method="rf",data=predDF)
predComb <- predict(combModFit,testing)
```

However, the code below seems to show that the combined model isn't generating new predictions, it's just recycling it's training info. The concrete differences between the code that works (above) & the code that doesn't work (below) are that the former effectively trains and predicts on labeled dataFrames of equal size, while the latter trains on a DF of 1 size and predicts on an unlabeled DF of another size.

```
#create a sudo holdout set by modifying the existing test set
library(dplyr)
otherTest <- testing %>% select(-diagnosis) #remove diagnosis so df is unlabled
otherTest <- otherTest[1:70,] # remove rows so that the test set changes size
newPreds <- predict(combModFit, otherTest) 
# Warning message: 'newdata' had 70 rows but variables found have 82 rows 
# newPreds now has 82 rows, but there were only 70 rows in otherTest to predict on. 

identical(predComb,newPreds) #TRUE
```

I'm entirely sure that I'm missing a simple concept, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: I am not clear how `predComb <- predict(combModFit,testing)` is working.  The model `combModFit` takes three predictors `predRF,predGBM,predLDA`, but none of these columns are in `testing`.

Comment: I agree Sam. Regardless of the dataset that is passed to combModFit, it makes the exact same predictions. predict(combModFit, iris) will also yield identical predictions. There seems to be something 'special' about predDF that causes this behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have searched through the source code for `predict.train`, and so far this is what I can make out

```
predict.train <- function (object, newdata = NULL, type = "raw", 
na.action = na.omit, ...)
```

In your function call

```
newPreds <- predict(combModFit, otherTest)
```

The parameters are set

```
object <- combModFit
newdata <- otherTest
```

Within the `predict.train` function are the lines

```
newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
rn <- row.names(newdata)
Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
      xlev = object$xlevels)
```

Where `Terms` is from `combModFit$terms` and is

```
diagnosis ~ predRF + predGBM + predLDA
```

Before deleting the response, when it becomes the formula

```
~ predRF + predGBM + predLDA
```

Now, back to the `model.frame` call, none of these column names are in the `testing` data frame

```
c("predRF", "predGBM", "predLDA") %in% names(testing)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But, earlier in your code you have defined objects `predRF`, `predGBM`, and `predLDA` as factors, each of length 82.  Therefore, `model.frame` does not return an error when it is called.   Instead, it just returns these three factors from before.

As a result, the object `m` is becomes a data frame with these three objects (as columns) and 82 rows.

Stating another way, `model.frame` is intended to extract columns from the `testing` data frame with names `predRF`, `predGBM`, and `predLDA`, but can't (because those columns don't exist).  Instead, it returns the objects you defined earlier.  Therefore, you get the same results no matter what `newdata` is, as long as they don't have the requisite column names.

**Edit:  To answer your question from the comments**

None of the variable names in `modRF$terms` correspond to objects in your environment.

```
table(all.vars(delete.response(modRF$terms)) %in% ls())
FALSE 
 130
```

Therefore, when you try to predict `modRF` with `cars` you get an error

```
predict(modRF, cars)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
object 'ACE_CD143_Angiotensin_Converti' not found
```

The first term in `modRF$terms` is not found

```
all.vars(delete.response(modRF$terms))[1]
[1] "ACE_CD143_Angiotensin_Converti"
```

However, the terms in `combModFit` do match the names of objects in the environment.

```
table(all.vars(delete.response(combModFit$terms)) %in% ls())
TRUE 
 3
```

So there is no error when you try to predict, although it is an unexpected result.

If you remove `predRF`, `predGBM`, and `predLDA` from the environment prior to running `predict(combModFit, cars)`, you will get an error.

```
# before deleting
predict(combModFit, cars)     
 [1] Control  Control  Impaired  ....

# after deleting the three objects you get an error
rm(list = c("predRF", "predGBM", "predLDA"))
predict(combModFit, cars)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'predRF' not found
```

Note that `predRF` is the first term from `combModFit`

```
all.vars(delete.response(combModFit$terms))[1]
[1] "predRF"
```

So the behavior of the `caret` function is consistent.  Your case is unusual in that some of the names of the terms in `combModFit` correspond to other objects in the environment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Thomas. Ensuring that DF's have the same column names does solve the problem that I reported, and makes this process fully functional. I think caret.Predict() should fail under the circumstances above instead of completing and returning nonsense. Does anyone else think this is a bug?

Comment: IMO, it's not a bug.  Just need to make sure that `newdata` has all of the right columns as predictors for the model.

Comment: Hold on. How does the explanation you've given explain why predict(baseModel, df) behaves differently than predict(combModFit, df)? predict(modRF,cars) will fail explicitly and return an error. predict(combModFit,cars) will complete and return predictions about Alzheimer's.

Comment: Great answer @SamThomas! I came across this by looking up stuff on the `caretEnsemble` package, but I've been in this situation myself and I know how confusing it can be...I found [this](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/12a31cncn3/r-predict-lm-if-regression-vector-is-longer-than-predicton-vector) forum very useful, especially the before-the-last answer there, but the one here is much more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

The [`caretEnsemble`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=caretEnsemble) package can do all of this for you.

Comment: caretEnsemble will not accept a generic list of train() objects as inputs, you are required to build all models at the same time and under the same conditions, which makes it unusable for some applications. Otherwise, I think caretEnsemble is great.

Comment: It will accept a generic list of train models (trained using caret::train) if you do the following: all.models <- list(model1,  model2, model3)
names(all.models) <- sapply(all.models, function(x) x$method)
class(all.models) <- "caretList"